# list all columns in table using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to list all columns using SQL query?

Comment: This is not a blog

Answer (score 1):

```
select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
    from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
    where table_name = '**table_name**';
```

This query helps retrieve all columns,datatype in particular table.

Comment: You might want to explain what the code does. Code only answers are rarely useful to future readers.

Comment: This query helps retrieve all columns, datatype in particular table.